# Javascript regex: Exclude/Delete a string from match

Tags: javascript, html, regex, href, substitution

Is there any other better alternative to exclude/delete a string from the match than creating additional capturing groups?

For example, I have:

```
<a href="./abcd/ZZZ/img.jpg">
```

And I want to get this:

```
<a href="./abcd/img.jpg">
```

For that I can write a regex code with 2 capturing groups:

```
(<a[^>]*)\/ZZZ([^>]*>)
```

Using `$1$2` as a substitution.

Let's say, is it possible to do this with one capturing group?

Comment: Are you using [tag:jQuery]? If yes, you can use `attr()` to change the `href` attribute value.

Comment: If your exclude string is static you can even use just `string.replace()`

Comment: How about you parse it as HTML first, then you find the `a` element and do `elem.href=elem.href.replace('/ZZZ')`?

Comment: You are right, eventually I used .replace() for my case.

Comment: But it would be nice to see if that exclusion could be worked out with only one capturing group.

Comment: You don't need any capturing groups; just replace `ZZZ` with an empty string.